# My Lambda is not able to access MySQL RDS. What to do?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have an architecture where the lambda would run when a irs data file is put on the S3 bucket, I can easily connect to my RDS on my local machine but for some very weird reason the Lambda is not able to access it and giving error:

```
  "errorMessage": "2022-11-15T22:22:51.919Z 9f20c035-5a47-4c6f-be9f-407b4a43aee6 Task timed out after 60.06 seconds"

2-11-15T22:21:53.402Z   9f20c035-5a47-4c6f-be9f-407b4a43aee6    URI updated to: https://irs-data.s3.amazonaws.com/?prefix=index&encoding-type=url
[DEBUG] 2022-11-15T22:21:53.402Z    9f20c035-5a47-4c6f-be9f-407b4a43aee6    Calculating signature using v4 auth.
[DEBUG] 2022-11-15T22:21:53.402Z    9f20c035-5a47-4c6f-be9f-407b4a43aee6    CanonicalRequest:
GET
/
encoding-type=url&prefix=index
host:irs-data.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
x-amz-date:20221115T222153Z
x-amz-security-token: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

host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
[DEBUG] 2022-11-15T22:21:53.439Z    9f20c035-5a47-4c6f-be9f-407b4a43aee6    StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20221115T222153Z
20221115/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request
5d61ffe01d9d6dd6aee4b1faeecbf21721efb8696f94f969389c93b05579847c
[DEBUG] 2022-11-15T22:21:53.439Z    9f20c035-5a47-4c6f-be9f-407b4a43aee6    Signature:
d6e70d2c6350adfa7231bd7b2a63e5ac2fd83583f5dde1dfada2b08854d493d2
[DEBUG] 2022-11-15T22:21:53.439Z    9f20c035-5a47-4c6f-be9f-407b4a43aee6    Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=GET, url=https://irs-data.s3.amazonaws.com/?prefix=index&encoding-type=url, headers={'User-Agent': b'Boto3/1.19.10 Python/3.9.13 Linux/4.14.255-285-225.501.amzn2.x86_64 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_python3.9 Botocore/1.22.12 Resource', 'X-Amz-Date': b'20221115T222153Z', 'X-Amz-Security-Token': b'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', 'X-Amz-Content-SHA256': b'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855', 'Authorization': b'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=ASIA6GM4LCU3GISECH6S/20221115/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token, Signature=d6e70d2c6350adfa7231bd7b2a63e5ac2fd83583f5dde1dfada2b08854d493d2'}>
[DEBUG] 2022-11-15T22:21:53.459Z    9f20c035-5a47-4c6f-be9f-407b4a43aee6    Certificate path: /var/task/botocore/cacert.pem
[DEBUG] 2022-11-15T22:21:53.459Z    9f20c035-5a47-4c6f-be9f-407b4a43aee6    Starting new HTTPS connection (1): irs-data.s3.amazonaws.com:443
2022-11-15T22:22:51.919Z 9f20c035-5a47-4c6f-be9f-407b4a43aee6 Task timed out after 60.06 seconds

END RequestId: 9f20c035-5a47-4c6f-be9f-407b4a43aee6
REPORT RequestId: 9f20c035-5a47-4c6f-be9f-407b4a43aee6  Duration: 60061.89 ms   Billed Duration: 60000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 116 MB Init Duration: 1040.64 ms
```

Lambda Code with S3 data:

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import logging
import sys
import time
import datetime as dt
import io
import pymysql

####### LOADING ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES #######
load_dotenv()
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

BUCKET = os.getenv('BUCKET')
BUCKET_PREFIX = os.getenv('BUCKET_PREFIX')

# Credentials to database connection
hostname= os.getenv('HOSTNAME')
dbname= os.getenv('DATABASE')
uname= os.getenv('USERNAME')
pwd= os.getenv('PASSWORD')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        logger.info("TEST")
        logger.info(BUCKET)

        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

        # assigning the bucket:
        my_bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET)

        data_list = []

        for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=BUCKET_PREFIX):
            if my_bucket_object.key.endswith(".csv"):
                key=my_bucket_object.key
                body=my_bucket_object.get()['Body'].read()
                temp_data = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(body))
                data_list.append(temp_data)
        
        # concatenating all the files together:
        df = pd.concat(data_list)

        # Connect to MySQL Database
        connection = pymysql.connect(host=hostname,user=uname,password=pwd,database=dbname)

        cursor = connection.cursor()

        # Truncate the table everytime before an ETL:
        sql_trunc = "TRUNCATE TABLE `irs990`"
        cursor.execute(sql_trunc)

        # commit the results
        connection.commit()

        # creating columns from the dataframe:
        cols = "`,`".join([str(i) for i in df.columns.tolist()])

        # adding dataframe to mysql RDS
        for i,row in df.iterrows():
            sql = "INSERT INTO `irs990` (`" +cols + "`) VALUES (" + "%s,"*(len(row)-1) + "%s)"
            cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
            connection.commit()

        # checking if data was successfully written:
        sql = "SELECT * FROM `irs990`"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        for i in result:
            print(i)

        # closing MySQL connection:
        connection.close()

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
```

My Lambda VPC details:

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvR0B.png)

My RDS details:

[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KWEd.png)

[image][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yDkl.png)

[image][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8q0I.png)

Can somebody please help me what to do? I am assigning the lambda the same VPC as the RDS, I tried using the same security group as well and making sure the outbound IP address of lambda is in the inbound rules for RDS. But nothing :(

Comment: You haven't provided any relevant information about your setup of SGs, lambda and RDS.

Comment: Okay let me share it over here

Answer (score 1):

The proper security configuration should be:

- A Security Group on the AWS Lambda function (`Lambda-SG`) that permits **All outbound access** (which is the default configuration)
- A Security Group on the Amazon RDS database (`DB-SG`) that permits inbound connections on port 3306 from `Lambda-SG`

That is, `DB-SG` should specifically reference `Lambda-SG`. This will then permit the incoming connection from the Lambda function.

Merely putting the Lambda function and the RDS database "in the same Security Group" is insufficient because security groups **apply to each resource *individually***. Unless the security group allows a connection from 'itself', this will not permit the desired access. Much better to use two security groups as described above.

Comment: John first of all thanks so much for your response, this makes so much sense. So I created a new security group for my lambda and allowed all traffic to pass both inbound and outbound (as it's just a POC test). 

How can I specifically reference my Lambda-SG inside the RDS SG? I went inside the inbound rules of my RDS SG and I entered the security group ID for my Lambda-SG inside the custom area and selected 'MYSQL/Aurora' in type and 'TCP' in the protocol area but still my lambda is failing.

Comment: It sounds like you have correctly configured the security groups. You could temporarily open all inbound ports on the `DB-SG` to determine whether it is causing the connectivity problem. If it is still failing, then something else is the problem. You can also use the **Reachability Analyzer** (shown in your screenshots) to check the network configuration. If everything looks okay, then it's either a problem with the Lambda function (is it connected to the VPC?) or the connection string.

Comment: Hey John, thanks again for your reply. So happy to hear you get back, so yes the VPC is assigned to the lambda, it's basically the same VPC which my RDS is using as well. But let me try the ports suggestion.

Comment: hey John I forgot to share my actual Lambda code where I am reading data from my S3 bucket which basically I want to write to my RDS. So I shared that code and upon checking the logs on my lambda I get no RDS connection error and just getting debugs of S3 and finally the logs are ending on:

"OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k" (I don't really know what this means)

Comment: My previous error was related to my lambda not accessing S3, so I created an endpoint. Now that error is fixed and finally I am getting an RDS error:

[ERROR] 2022-11-16T10:07:28.226Z d8640acb-d476-403a-b4ef-3a976ccc503b (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol)")

Comment: The mention of `localhost` would suggest that the Lambda code is attempting to connect to a database locally, rather than on Amazon RDS. Check your code and make sure it is connecting to the right destination server. Without seeing your code, I can't really comment on what's wrong.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for getting back. I did upload my entire lambda code to the original question. In my .env file i gave all my database credentials and in my hostname i am actually giving  my database endpoint. I am not supplying the port number....is that reason why this could be failing?

Comment: I suggest you add some debugging statements (using `print()`) to help identify which line is causing the problem (presumably the `pymysql.connect()`) line -- the remainder of the code is irrelevant if it is failing there. Print the values of the variables being passed to `connect()` to verify that they contain the expected values: `print(f'host={hostname},user={uname},password={pwd},database={dbname}')`

Comment: John you were right doing the print debug literally helped me solve the issue, the issue was with my env variables. Thanks alot! stay blessed